# How do I add a Google Assistant command to a button on the homescreen?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, google-assistant

I'd like to add a widget/shortcut/whatever to the home screen that would allow me to execute a google assistant command as if I had said it.

For example, "Turn off the Livingroom TV".

This would be extremely useful, as it would allow me to dedicate a page in my launcher to home automation tasks. Sometimes it's not reasonable to use my voice (baby on lap for example) and while I'm aware I can hold the home button then click the keyboard icon, I was hoping there was a quicker/easier way.

Although I'd prefer a general answer, I'm using an LG V30+, running Android 8.0.0 if you have any more specific ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since asking this question, Google has release an app called [Action Blocks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.accessibility.maui.actionblocks) which does literally exactly what I'm asking for in this question.

With it, you can create "actions" which are either from one of the predefined examples or you can type in arbitrary text which would be parsed as if you typed (or said) it into google assistant directly. These actions can be attached to the homescreen as widgets.

It's not the fastest application in the world, and it's still a bit buggy at time of writing, but it's also only about a week old so I imagine it'll get more solid over time.

---

Another new alternative that has come to the surface since writing this answer, is the [Home Assistant](https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/google_assistant/) integration. Those with a technical inclination will likely prefer this method. For me, it's been vastly more reliable than google's action blocks and far more customisable and was easy to set up seeing as I already run a home assistant server (though admittedly not as easy as action blocks).

Answer (score 1):

There is [Assistant Shortcuts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=host.stjin.assistantshortcuts) app on Google Play. I haven't tried it myself, but I think it is a possible solution to your request.

Comment: I appreciate the idea but reading the description it looks like the app you mention is deprecated in favour of one with pretty low reviews. I'll give it a try if no other answers come to the surface.

Comment: I had a bit of a look at this application - and it does handle some phone automation tasks, but I couldn't find a way to trigger google actions that aren't related to that specific device.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a routine in the Google Home app, you can then add that routine to your home screen on your device.  No need for extra apps other than the official Google Home app.